# Can I remove this HVAC damper?

Tags: hvac, vent

Is is possible to remove this damper? It looks like there are special kind of screws about an inch above but I'm not sure how those would come out. If I can't be remove could it be cut out? I have an oscillating tool so I thought maybe there would be an attachment made for HVAC.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why a standard round grill won’t fit. We put dampers in to control air flow and balance rooms. taking it out may be a mistake. The screws that attach the damper to the duct are about 4” up I can see 1 at about 9 o’clock position, , as jack mentions those in your photo are rivets.

Comment: It's hard to see in my picture but in the bottom one you can see it's almost against the sidewall. A round grill won't fit because the sidewall is too close. If there was a square grill that would fit in there then that would work. The previous owner had a round grill on it that they cut part of it off to make it fit. Needless to say that didn't look very good. It would be nice to have the damper feature but this is in our master bathroom so we've always left it wide open to try and keep it comfortable in there.

Answer (score 1):

Those are rivets and you normally have to drill or grind them out. You can probably get in there with a rotary tool like a Dremel with a grinding wheel on it. If not, get a hack saw and just cut the bracket on each side to remove the internal parts and leave the rivets there. Is there a particular reason you want to remove it?

Comment: The vent is too close to the wall so a circular cover doesn't fit on it. I was going to get the damper off then maybe just throw a sidewall grill over the top for the time being until it gets moved.